# How to escape special char when use glib.string.escape()

Tags: gtk, glib, vala

Due to the document of glib.string.escape()

> Escapes the special characters '\b', '\f', '\n', '\r', '\t', '\v', '\' and '"' in the string source by inserting a '\' before them.
>
> Additionally all characters in the range 0x01-0x1F (everything below SPACE) and in the range 0x7F-0xFF (all non-ASCII chars) are replaced with a '\' followed by their octal representation. Characters supplied in exceptions are not escaped.

Now I want **not** eacape "0x7F-0xFF" characters. How to write the **exceptions** part?

my example code no work.

```
            shellcmd = "bash -c \""+file.get_string(title,"List").escape("0x7F-0xFF")+"\"";
            print("shellcmd: %s\n", shellcmd);
            Process.spawn_command_line_sync (shellcmd,
            out ls_stdout, out ls_stderr, out ls_status);
            if(ls_status!=0){ list = ls_stderr.split("\n"); }
            else{ list = ls_stdout.split("\n"); }
```

---

this works.

```
shellcmd = "bash -c \""+file.get_string(title,"Check").replace("\"","\\\"")+"\"";
```

Answer (score 2):

You actually have to put the characters `0x7f` to `0xff` in the `exceptions` argument. So something like:

```
shellcmd = "bash -c \""+file.get_string(title,"List").escape("\x7F\x80\x81\x82…\xfe\xff")+"\"";
```

You would need to list them all manually.

Looking more generally at your code, you seem to be constructing a command to run. This is a very bad idea and you should never do it. It is wide open to [code injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_injection). Use `Process.spawn_sync()` and pass it an argument vector instead.

Comment: It's too much trouble to list all characters. anyway thanks. I've implemented it in other ways by simplly only replace all double quotation marks with \", and there's no problem now. .

Comment: Your design is inherently subject to code injection. You should change it.

Comment: My design is read command from an ini file, take the result to display. It just like call some bash in a perl script. What's the problem?